# PHP "foreach" incrementation of a value if a certain condition is met

Tags: php, foreach

I have this loop:

```
<?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>

<?php if ($option_value['quantity'] <= 0) { ?>

What code should be put here?

<?php } ?>

<?php } ?>

<?php echo $i; ?>
```

Let's say the loop is 10 rounds. So, when **$option_value['quantity'] <= 0** I need some variable to count it, and if the condition of **$option_value['quantity'] <= 0** is met 3 times during those 10 rounds, I want the variable which counts that to have a value of 3, and **echo** it at the end. So, any help would be appreciated. I've tried something with **i++** etc. but I don't know how to define it in order to make it work and count if the condition is met.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even a bare `$i++;` would work (albeit with a notice). It's hard to imagine that you didn't try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to initialize `$i` outside the scope of the foreach loop and then increment it each time the condition is true:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
    if ($option_value['quantity'] <= 0) {
        $i++;
    }
} 
echo $i;
?>
```

Comment: There you go, I totally forgot about **$i = 0;** :) Thanks buddy, really appreciate your help ;) Btw, all **{** and **}** are not needed, and there's a missing **;** after the **$i++** ;)

Comment: I know I could omit the braces, but it's good to get in the habit of using them anyway, as it makes code is much more readable and maintainable.